# Keep function namespace alive for debugging in IPython

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

In IPython, is there a way to import the namespace of a function into the interactive environment? For example, if I have a script, say, `script.py`:

```
def foo(x,y):
    z = x + y
    return z

a = 1
b = 2
c = foo(a,b)
```

and at the IPython prompt I write:

```
>> run script.py
```

Everything defined in `script.py` becomes a part of my environment, so if I write:

```
>> a
```

I'll get back `1`.

What I want to do is to be able to dump the namespace of the function I call into my interpreter namespace so I can inspect the objects. Something like:

```
>> runfunction foo(1,2)
>> z
```

and get back that the value of `z` is `3`.

I know about `ipdb.set_trace()`, and I could just add that to the end of my function to automatically enter the debugger, but I may not want to do this every time.

If this functionality doesn't exist, what is the recommended way to inspect the values of variables within a function for debugging purposes, though perhaps not *every* time I run it?

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea. If you have a function with a local variable named, say, `map`, calling that function would overwrite or hide any global or builtin named `map` (in this case, the very useful builtin function). So an awful lot of code would just stop working if you did this.

Comment: Anyway, what's wrong with just setting a breakpoint inside the function?

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to do something like storing `locals()` or `sys._getframe()` in a single global variable (as a dict or namespace), instead of dumping it all on top of `globals`. Then you can inspect that global variable whenever you want, or just not do so when you don't want to. It would mean you have to write `_last.z` instead of `z`, but it also means that you're overwriting `_last.map`, which is fine, instead of `map`, which is not.

Comment: You're overthinking it. If you don't want to set a breakpoint, stick in a few `if DEBUG: print whatever` type lines, where `DEBUG` is a boolean that sits at the top of script.py or is a parameter to your funtion.

Comment: @abarnert: I'm aware that there might be name collisions, but since this is for quick-and-dirty debugging, and not production code, I'm not too concerned about that. Besides, there are *already* name collisions in the current behavior of the %run magic in IPython: the module's top level names collide with whatever is in the interpreter namespace.

Comment: @MrE: That's a lot like the functionality I'd like, I'm just wondering if there is a built-in way of doing this in the IPython interpreter, without making all of these debug statements. When it comes down to it, I know that these debug methods exist, I'm just wondering if there is a more comfortable way that fits my workflow.

Comment: @jme: Yes, but modules generally don't have functions or global variables named `map` or `dir` (unless they specifically don't want to call the builtins); functions very frequently have local variables with names like that.

Comment: To update my own quest, one possible route is to use the `to_user_ns()` function provided by `IPython.ipapi`, though I'm having some trouble finding it in the most recent IPython distribution.

Comment: I posted an answer to a very similar question here: [save variable to interactive namespace from python debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18125590/1599111). The example I used there just assigns a single variable, but it should be easy to adapt to your needs.

Comment: If it's running inside IPython, I think you can add `get_ipython().push(locals())` to the function. ([Docs for the push() method](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.push))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sys.settrace`, here is an example, I save the locals dict to an attribute of the wrap function:

```
import sys

def get_locals(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        sys.settrace(tracefunc)
        try:
            res = func(*args, **kw)
        finally:
            sys.settrace(None)
        return res

    def tracefunc(frame, event, arg):
        if event == "return":
            if frame.f_code is func.func_code:
                wrap.last_res = frame.f_locals
        return tracefunc    

    return wrap

@get_locals
def foo(x,y):
    z = x + y
    return z

def bar(x, y):
    z = x - y
    return z

a = 1
b = 2
c = foo(a, b)
d = bar(a, b)

print foo.last_res
```

output:

```
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
```

If you want it be globals, you can update global dict with the locals dict.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, and I think I can get it to  work to my liking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with doing typical debugging here?

```
> run -d program.py
> b program.py:282 #(line#)
```

You can even set a condition with:

```
> condition 2 a == 2 # where 2 is the breakpoint, 1 is by default first line
```

You can inspect the option with the breakpoint when in that scope.